# how to discuss about two incongruous issues?

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-request

I want to imply something cannot happen if we must obey something else or be loyal to a rule, restriction, etc.. For example, consider the relation between power consumption and performance of a electronic device. We have some constraints on power called power budget that we cannot violate it.
I have written down below sentences:

1. > The high performance requirement cannot be satisfied while being loyal to the power budget.
2. > The high performance requirement cannot be satisfied by following the power budget.
3. > It is impossible to meet high performance requirement and be loyal to the power budget simultaneously.
4. > It is impossible to satisfy the high performance requirement without violating the power budget.

   I think there is perfect word describing: "something happening is not feasible if something else must be happened".

---

Q1: Which sentence do you prefer ?

Q2 : Is there any special or well-known structure used to discuss about such issues?

I would be happy to have your comments.
Regards

Comment: This might end up opinion based, but I would prefer 1., because it uses "while" to connect the contrasting phrases.

Answer (score 1):

All are correct. Here some sentences from me.

> 1. The high performance requirement can violate the power budget.
> 2. The high performance requirement is not possible with power budget.
> 3. The high performance requirement is not possible in compliance with power budget.
> 4. We can meet the high performance requirement in violation of power budget.
> 5. The power budget impedes the high performance requirement.
> 6. The power budget fends off the high performance requirement.